Quadric equation in Projective Geometry
It is well known that 5 points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ define a conic. While studying the book Geometry II by Marcel Berger, I came across a theorem stating that 9 points in $P\mathbb{R}^3$ define a quadric. However, the book does not provide examples on this topic. Later, Berger gives a beautiful example of how to find the conic that passes through 5 given points. In this context, $n$ refers to the dimension of the space $P(E)$:
"For example, if $n = 2$ and $\phi$, $\psi$, $\xi$, and $\eta$ are equations (linear forms in $E$) for the lines $\langle m_1, m_2 \rangle$, $\langle m_3, m_4 \rangle$, $\langle m_1, m_3 \rangle$, and $\langle m_2, m_4 \rangle$, respectively, the pencil $\mathscr{F}$ of all conics going through $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$, and $m_4$ will be defined by the equations $\lambda \phi \psi + \lambda' \xi \eta$.''
"
I wonder if I can use the same construction in $P\mathbb{R}^3$ to obtain an equation of a quadric for 9 given points, or if the easiest way of constructing such a quadric would be to take a generic equation of a quadric, such as $A x^2 + B y^2 + C z^2 + D xy + \dots + I z = 0$, and evaluate it for the points.

You mean $\Bbb P^3(\Bbb R)$?
